# Java Application Client Freezed with an JNIWrapper exception

Tags: java

I am implementing java application to communicate with windows dll files through a `C++ JNI bridge`. 
Some point, with the following error, my java application is getting freezed.

```
java.lang.NoSuchMethodException: java.lang.System.getCallerClass()
    at java.lang.Class.getDeclaredMethod(Class.java:2130) ~[na:1.8.0_121]
    at com.jniwrapper.Library.unloadNativeCode(SourceFile:181) ~[jniwrap-3.8.4.jar:na]
    at com.jniwrapper.NativeResourceCollector.d(SourceFile:252) [jniwrap-3.8.4.jar:na]
    at com.jniwrapper.NativeResourceCollector.a(SourceFile:77) [jniwrap-3.8.4.jar:na]
    at com.jniwrapper.NativeResourceCollector.c(SourceFile:22) [jniwrap-3.8.4.jar:na]
    at com.jniwrapper.n.run(SourceFile:141) [jniwrap-3.8.4.jar:na]
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This method was [removed in JDK8](https://hg.openjdk.java.net/jdk8/jdk8/jdk/file/687fd7c7986d/src/share/classes/java/lang/System.java), while it was [still there](http://hg.openjdk.java.net/jdk7/jdk7/jdk/file/cf44386c8fe3/src/share/classes/java/lang/System.java#l1210) in JDK7.

As jniwrapper is a commercial product, you should ask them for an updated version. From [the release notes](http://jniwrapper-support.teamdev.com/updates), version 3.10 should do the trick.

Comment: Yes, I think so.
Thank you.